# Planetary motion: with a different nature of potential. Condition for circular orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, orbital-motion, centrifugal-force

> Consider a particle moving in the potential $U (r)= -A/r^n$, where $A>0$. What are the values of $n$ which admit stable circular orbits?

I tried to solve by putting $dr/dt=0$ in the total energy equation $E= T + U_\mathrm{eff}$, but it didn't work. Then I came across a solution which said that for the orbit to be circular, $U_\mathrm{eff}(r)$ needs to have a minimum when plotted against $r$, where $U_\mathrm{eff}$ is the effective potential $(L^2/2mr^2+ U (r))$. But I don't understand why it has to, because when $n=1$, where circular orbits are possible, $U_\mathrm{eff}$ does not have a minimum since it varies with $1/r$.

Comment: It is tempting to mention [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem): One may show that if a slightly deformed circular orbit should remain closed, then the central force has to be the inverse square law or Hooke's law.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got this idea:

> when $n=1$, where circular orbits are possible, $U_\mathrm{eff}=L^2/2mr^2+ U (r)$ does not have a minimum since it varies with $1/r$.

Here, have a look at that function:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At small $r$, the $+1/r^2$ dominates and the function is positive and monotonously decreasing. At large $r$, the $-1/r$ term dominates and the function is negative but monotonously increasing. The only way to reconcile those two behaviours is to have a minimum in the middle, which can easily be found by setting $\frac{\mathrm dU_\mathrm{eff}}{\mathrm dr}=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. But is there any explanation behind why $Ueff $ should have a minima for circular orbits?

Comment: @PrashantGovind Have you ever seen a particle sit still, stably, in anything other than a minimum?

Comment: Also, some formatting notes: 'minima' is plural, 'minimum' is singular. And you typeset $U_\mathrm{eff}$ as `$U_\mathrm{eff}$`.